# How to set interface for eth0 when pi connected to laptop?

Tags: pi-3

Ok, I am trying to set a static IP for my Pi3 and i use Raspbian Jessie OS. I know that we need to modify the `dhcpcd.conf`file within /etc/ location. I have had two additions to it - namely `eth0` and `wlan0`. My pi is connected to my laptop using an ethernet cable. Now for the `interface eth0` part what should be the value of the `static routers` and `static_domain_name` entries? Should it be set to the ip of my laptop or the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not need all that. Just edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to have:

`auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.0.2.7
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.0.2.254`

instead of

`auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp`

Change this entry for your numbers, obvisouly. 
[Here's](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration) the wiki for Debian networking if you need more.